# Rewring error at proxy

Tags: nginx

The URL `teste.oficial.news/my1`  returns status 404, and `teste.oficial.news/other` status 400... But files and PHP are fine.

```
server {
        server_name  teste.oficial.news;

        root    /var/www/teste;
        index   index.php index.html index.htm;

        location  / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
        }

        location  @proxy {
             rewrite (my[23])$   ETC.php?cmd=$1
                 last;
             rewrite other$      index.html
                 break;
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        }

        location  ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        include  snippets/ssl-oficial.news.conf;

} #end server
```

what is worng?

Comment: what's running on http://127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Hi @FedericoGalli, at localhost only the NGINX server at WWW... but I will use other ports with Python, etc. Ex. will change to `127.0.0.1:1234`... Supposing no impact.

Comment: if you see in your debug logs the rewrite rules being hitted and working, then are passed to the proxy wich then should pass into the php section but in that passage something appens

Comment: @FedericoGalli and all,  get a bounty for similar problem, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45056818).

Comment: Can you show what files are there?  Also, who is giving out the errors you indicate -- do they have nginx signature, or the signature of any of your upstreams?

Comment: @PeterKrauss, is there anything that remains to be answered about this question?  If not, could you please accept?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried a sample nginx configuration file similar to the one you describe:

```
   root /var/www/teste;
   rewrite other$ index.html break;
```

After doing a `curl localhost/this/or/other`, this is the error message that gets produced in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, as per `tail /var/log/nginx/error.log`:

`2017/07/24 08:21:32 [error] 45637#0: *1 open() "/var/www/testeindex.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /this/or/other HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost`

Unless such file is present in your system, you will likewise be receiving a similar message for similar reasons.

Same for your `rewrite (my[23])$   ETC.php?cmd=$1` fragment.

***Solution***:  rewrite the files correctly — if the `replacement` part of `rewrite` does not start with either scheme or slash, you're probably doing something wrong.  Sprinkle some `/` symbols in your `rewrite` directives.